# How many ways can $n$ spaces be used with blocks of size $\le n$ (or leave empty)

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways $n$ spaces be 'used' with blocks of size $\le n$

*and counting empty spaces as a way of using them.*

The first thing came to my mind is to calculate compositions of n (like partitions but with order) so there are $2^{n-1}$ possible [compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29), for example

$2^{3-1}=4$

```
   1) 3 = 3    
   2) 3 = 2 + 1     
   3) 3 = 1 + 2     
   4) 3 = 1 + 1 + 1
```

But!, this doesn't count any zero values!

So I think in summing up the previous compositions till n, $\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{k-1} = 2^n-1$ so for example adding these combinations

```
   5) 2 = 2 + 0 
   6) 2 = 1 + 1 + 0

   7) 1 = 1 + 0 + 0
```

$2^n-1=7$

But this is wrong! because it would not count "left zeros" nor "intermediate zeros" I mean, I need to count also these sums

```
2 = 0 + 2
2 = 1 + 0 + 1
2 = 0 + 1 + 1
1 = 0 + 1 + 0
1 = 0 + 0 + 1 
0 = 0 + 0 + 0
```

How can this be calculated?

Comment: For $n = 3$ do we also need to count $2 = 1+0+1$, $2 = 0+1+1$, and $0 = 0+0+0$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 yes you are right, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T_n$ be the number of ways to fill $n$ spaces.

Case 0: The leftmost space is empty.

After leaving that space empty, there are $T_{n-1}$ ways to use the remaining $n-1$ spaces.

Case k (for $1 \le k \le n$): The left most space is occupied by a block of length $k$.

After laying down the block of length $k$, there are $n-k$ spaces left, and thus, $T_{n-k}$ ways to use these spaces.

Adding these up yields $T_n = 2T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3} + \cdots + T_{1} + T_{0}$.

To simplify the recurrence relation, note that $T_{n+1} = 2T_{n} + T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + \cdots + T_{1} + T_{0}$.

Subtraction yields $T_{n+1} - T_n = 2T_n - T_{n-1}$, i.e. $T_{n+1} = 3T_n - T_{n-1}$.

Clearly, there is $T_0 = 1$ way to use $0$ spaces, and $T_1 = 2$ ways to use $1$ space.

Now, you have a linear recurrence relation and initial conditions. :)

Note: I'm assuming that $0 = 0+0+\cdots+0+0$ counts as a way to use $n$ spaces. If it doesn't, then you should compute $T_n - 1$ instead.

Comment: +1 for induction, although I am not sure to agree in "1 way of using 0 spaces", (I think there is no way of using '0 spaces'), but leaving that case aside numbers seems to fit!

Answer (score 1):

Generate the sequence for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$, which is:

$1,2,5,13,34,89,233,610,1597,4181,\ldots$

and take it to OEIS. We will find these related sequences: [A001519](http://oeis.org/A001519), [A122367](http://oeis.org/A122367) and [A099496](http://oeis.org/A099496)

In summary, the recurrence is:

$$
a_n=3\, a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} \hspace{20mm} a_0=1,a_1=2
$$
also $$a_n=\operatorname{Fibonacci}(2\, n+1)$$

and the generating function is:
$$G(x)=\frac{1-x}{1-3\, x+x^2}$$

Comment: Although I would prefer to understand a proof/induction/whatever, it's anyway a good advice to search OEIS first! +1

Comment: It sure is, because we will get many leads about the problem, in many cases pointers to the solution also!